# SQL use COUNT() in WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server

I have a table like this

```
Reserve_Id|Reserve_Date|ESId|FareId|PassengerId|TicketId|UserAccId|TotalTicketPrice|Reservation Status
======================================================================================================
3         | 2020-08-15 | 2  | 10   | 5         | 20     | 2       | 147.05         | Rescheduled
4         | 2020-08-16 | 4  | 1    | 6         | 28     | 1       | 16.5           | Reserved
5         | 2020-08-16 | 5  | 5    | 10        | 28     | 1       | 128            | Reserved
```

I want to get the data which is same account ID and same ticket ID. This is my Code

```
Select Passengers.F_Name, Passengers.L_Name, year(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - year(Passengers.P_DOB) as 'Age', Passengers.P_Phone, Passengers.P_Email, Passengers.P_Address, Passengers.P_DOB, Aircraft.Aircraft_Name, Aircraft.Airline_Name, Airport.Airport_Name, Airport.Country, Airport.City, ExtraService.ES_Description, FlightTicket.Ticket_DepartDate, FlightTicket.Ticket_DepartTime, FlightReservation.Reserve_Date from Passengers 
join FlightReservation on Passengers.P_Id = FlightReservation.PassengerId 
join FlightTicket on FlightReservation.TicketId = FlightTicket.Ticket_Id
join FlightRoute on FlightTicket.TicketRoute_Id = FlightRoute.Route_Id
join Aircraft on FlightRoute.Aircraft_Id = Aircraft.Aircraft_Id
join Airport on FlightRoute.DepartAirport_Id = Airport.Airport_Id
join ExtraService on FlightReservation.ESId = ExtraService.ES_Id
where (year(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - year(P_DOB) < 17) and count(FlightReservation.TicketId) = 1 and count(FlightReservation.UserAccId) > 1 and FlightReservation.ReservationStatus <> 'Cancelled'
```

I want to get the data where the passenger age is less than 17 and he is alone.

```
select count(a.TicketId) as 'Ticket', count(a.UserAccId) as 'User', TicketId, UserAccId as UserId from FlightReservation a 
join Passengers p on p.P_Id = a.PassengerId
where a.ReservationStatus <> 'Cancelled' and (year(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - year(p.P_DOB) < 17)
group by a.TicketId, UserAccId 
having COUNT(a.TicketId) = 1 and COUNT(UserAccId) >= 1
```

I tried this having count statement to check the output of quesry and the result is

```
Ticket|User|TicketId|UserId
===========================
1     | 1  | 28     | 1
1     | 1  | 20     | 2
```

The expected result I need is show TicketId = 20 only.
The table for Passengers

```
P_Id|F_Name     |L_Name   |P_Phone|P_Email|P_Address|P_DOB
==============================================================
1   |Jack       |Sparrow  |12345  |asd    |.........|1975-08-11
2   |Samuel     |Meade    |12345  |asd    |.........|1999-03-07
3   |George     |Gibson   |12345  |asd    |.........|1989-08-22
4   |Robert     |Salcedo  |12345  |asd    |.........|2007-10-15
5   |Mark       |Lalonde  |12345  |asd    |.........|2005-01-17
6   |Shirley    |Rodriguez|12345  |asd    |.........|2019-05-27
7   |Gilbert    |Brandon  |12345  |asd    |.........|2013-02-19
8   |Olivia     |Nielsen  |12345  |asd    |.........|2015-06-17
9   |Christopher|Nielsen  |12345  |asd    |.........|1985-03-12
10  |Mary       |Nielsen  |12345  |asd    |.........|1982-11-19
11  |Nancy      |Angeles  |12345  |asd    |.........|1950-07-27
12  |Shirley    |Rodriguez|12345  |asd    |.........|1947-08-20
```

Comment: Try `COUNT(UserAccId) > 1` rather then `>=`

Comment: It show empty, I think is it read the condition so only show 2 row...

Comment: Please provide the sample data for the tables your are joining in your last query (`FlightReservation` and `Passengers`). You only join on `p.P_Id = a.PassengerId`, any chance you are unintentionally counting data from other routes/planes/airports that have the same passenger id?

Comment: The first query I insert after remove the count also show the 2 data which is below 17 age. But I want to get the person who travel alone only...

Comment: So if a ticket was issued last year for flights taken last year (or perhaps for flights to be taken in December) you only consider age of passenger **right now**?

Comment: Yes. I only consider their age right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
/* PASSENGERS MOCK-UP */
DECLARE @Passengers TABLE ( P_ID INT, P_DOB DATE, F_Name VARCHAR(30), L_Name VARCHAR(30) );
INSERT INTO @Passengers ( P_ID, P_DOB, F_Name, L_Name ) VALUES 
    ( 5, '07/01/2004', 'Michael', 'Meyers' ),
    ( 6, '06/11/1968', 'Snake', 'Plissken' ),
    ( 10, '04/02/1952', 'Bob', 'Gray' );

/* FLIGHT RESERVATION MOCK-UP */
DECLARE @FlightReservation TABLE (
    Reserve_Id INT, Reserve_Date DATE, ESId INT, FareId INT, PassengerId INT, TicketId INT, UserAccId INT, TotalTicketPrice DECIMAL(18,2), ReservationStatus VARCHAR(20)
);
INSERT INTO @FlightReservation (
    Reserve_Id, Reserve_Date, ESId, FareId, PassengerId, TicketId, UserAccId, TotalTicketPrice, ReservationStatus
) VALUES
    ( 3, '2020-08-15', 2, 10, 5, 20, 2, 147.05, 'Rescheduled' ),
    ( 4, '2020-08-16', 4, 1, 6, 28, 1, 16.5, 'Reserved' ),
    ( 5, '2020-08-16', 5, 5, 10, 28, 1, 128, 'Reserved' );

/*
    Return passengers under the age of 17 traveling alone.
*/
SELECT 
    Passengers.P_ID,
    Passengers.F_Name,
    Passengers.L_Name,
    Passengers.P_DOB,
    YEAR ( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) - YEAR ( Passengers.P_DOB ) AS 'Age',
    FlightReservation.TicketId
FROM @Passengers AS Passengers
INNER JOIN @FlightReservation AS FlightReservation
    ON Passengers.P_ID = FlightReservation.PassengerId
WHERE
    YEAR ( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) - YEAR ( P_DOB ) < 17
    AND EXISTS (

        -- Restrict resultset to reservations having a single count of a TicketId --
        SELECT * FROM @FlightReservation AS x 
        WHERE
            x.TicketId = FlightReservation.TicketId
        GROUP BY x.TicketId
        HAVING COUNT ( x.TicketId ) = 1
    
    );
```

Returns

```
+------+---------+--------+------------+-----+----------+
| P_ID | F_Name  | L_Name |   P_DOB    | Age | TicketId |
+------+---------+--------+------------+-----+----------+
|    5 | Michael | Meyers | 2004-07-01 |  16 |       20 |
+------+---------+--------+------------+-----+----------+
```